# Tyre pressure for Toyota Yaris

Tags: tires

I have new Toyota Yaris Trend 2013 and wondering what should be the tyre pressure in front and rear tyres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tire pressures are listed on a sticker in the drivers door jam.

Here is an example of what you are looking for.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had a look at my door and there is no such thing :(

Comment: @Makky check the door and jam of all the doors. It may be on either. Other places used are the glove box or where the spare tire is located. Look in the owners manual it should tell you the location of the sticker.

Comment: I'll have a look at those places today :)

Comment: also sometimes under the fuel filler flap.

Comment: It was located in glove box.

Answer (score 2):

You can have three tyre sizes on your car, 165/70 14, 32Front 32Rear; 175/65 14, 32F 32R; 205/45 17 29F 28R. As Larry has pointed out, you will find a decal giving tyre sizes and pressures on the door jamb or on the inside of the fuel flap. They will also be present in the vehicles handbook.